# Springboot Hibernate Query: filter by childrens attributes

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot

Hi I have a problem generating a @query in my SpringBoot repo. Using hibernate.

My POJOs:

```
class Offer
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@ManyToMany
private List<Attribute> attributes;
@ManyToMany
private List<Offer> offers;
```

and

```
class Attribute
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

It works this way to get the "offer.offers by attribute". But now I want to enhance my query to get "offer offer.offers.attribute" an I strugle with it.

What I want is to find all Offers which have "**Offer.attribute == 1**" **AND** "**all Offer.offers.attribute == 2**"

Ending with this query:

```
@query
"SELECT o FROM Offer o "
+ "JOIN o.attributes a "
+ "LEFT OUTER JOIN o.offers oo "
+ "LEFT OUTER JOIN o.offers.attributes ooa " <-- Problem issue
+ "WHERE o.status = 1 "
+ "AND oo.status = 1 " 
+ "AND a.id = 100 " 
+ "AND ooa.id = 101 " 
+ "GROUP BY o.id "
```

But upon compilation I get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection 
[offer0_.id.offers] with element property reference [attributes]
```

Now I wonder how to do it correctly?
Hope some SQL/Hibernate hero can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Gregor

Answer (score 1):

Well... Iam one step further:

this query works:

```
@query
"SELECT o FROM Offer o "
+ "JOIN o.attributes a "
+ "LEFT OUTER JOIN o.offers oo "
+ "LEFT OUTER JOIN oo.attributes ooa " <-- referencin JOIN
+ "WHERE o.status = 1 "
+ "AND oo.status = 1 " 
+ "AND a.id = 100 " 
+ "AND ooa.id = 101 " 
+ "GROUP BY o.id "
```

But now I get all results with at least on "Offers.offer.attributes == 101"
But I need all offers.offer having that attribute.

Any hints how to continue?